# Clarification of usage <<refine>> vs. <<satisfy>> relationship in sysml

Tags: relationship, sysml

I am new to uml/sysml and want to understand clearly the usage of *refine* vs. *satisfy* in a requirements diagram.

I am intending to create a requirements diagrams that are mapped to functions in an activity diagram to the appropriate functional requirement.

From reading several books, the definition of a *refine* relationship is as follows:

> The refine requirement relationship can be used to describe how a
>   model element, or set of elements, can be used to further refine a
>   requirement. For example, a use case or activity diagram may be used
>   to refine a text-based functional requirement

And the definition of a *satisfy* relationship is:

> The satisfy relationship describes how a design or implementation
>   model concept satisfies one or more requirements

So if have a function in an activity diagram, would you use a *refine* or a *satisfy* relationship to map to a requirement?

See [Example image showing the mapping of a function to a requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnkcL.png)

Thank you for your inputs and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an activity diagram you cannot have a function directly, just actions. You should use an operation call action in the activity diagram which can refer the function.

**The function should be a part of the design so I think you should use satisfy.**

Comment: well, to be fair: you can have whatever you want. Is it normative: probably not.  However, refine relationships, in my anecdotal preference, means that I am further specifying the nature of a generalized requirement.  I also tend to want to use satisfy wherever I want to demarcate a model element is being depended upon by the requirement (as _refined_ or as general a requirement as you want to track) to be 'met' or 'satisfied'.